# Node JS: Running server all the time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, forever

I was wondering if anyone had some insight on running a Node API app built with Express. I built a set of API end points using Express and I uploaded the Node app to my server on A Small Orange. The issue is that once I start the app through my terminal I have to keep the terminal open and my computer on in order to keep the API end points up and running.

I started to experiment with the npm forever-monitor, but it keeps crashing when I run express and forever-monitor in the same app.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: try using nohup http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup

Comment: you can use the screen command before you start node so it keeps running after you close the console.

Comment: forever start <you_start_app.js>
and really forever --help

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. It is on a shared server with preinstalled NPMs. I can't run forever as a command. Everything has to be run inside of a node script. Not the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Install forever

```
npm install -g forever
```

then run your app

```
forever start app.js
```

and see

```
forever --help
```

for options and more...

Comment: Yeah I can't do that. It is on a shared server with preinstalled NPMs

Comment: I think you need to apply a suitable environment /
although it is obvious but it is a reality